# Pass Username to MainFrom from Login

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I have a login form with this code:

```
    public bool FMP = false;
    public void login()
    {
        try
        {
            string utilizadores = "Select * FROM Utilizador where Nome=@Nome";
            SqlConnection conn;
            SqlCommand cmd;
            SqlDataReader dr;

            conn = new SqlConnection(Ligacao.cn);
            conn.Open();
            cmd = new SqlCommand(utilizadores, conn);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Nome", textBox1.Text));
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                Dados.nome = Convert.ToString(dr["Nome"]);
                Dados.password = Convert.ToString(dr["Password"]);
                Dados.nivel = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Nivel"]);
            }
            conn.Close();

            if (Dados.password == textBox2.Text)
            {
                FMP = true;
                this.Dispose();

            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Login Incorrecto!");
                FMP = false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ERRO" + ex);
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        login();

    }
}
```

after this, and if the login was successful, the mainform of the app is launched!
So, in the mainform, i need to get the username that was inserted in the textbox, i need to pass the value (like a Session ID) to a label, but i can't figure it out. Can anyone help me here?

Comment: Use Sessions. You would have to remove the session at one point. Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx

Comment: What's with this session stuff, was there an ASP.NET tag on this question?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17779355/session-in-wpf

Comment: Thak you guys, even that i didn't used this way to resolve the problem i'll study it, seems to be very nice to use sessions like php apps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create one static class with property like

```
public static class Globals
{
    public static string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

And then assign the User name to the `Property UserName`

```
if (Dados.password == textBox2.Text)
{
     Globals.UserName=Dados.nome; //or you can directy assign Globals.UserName=textBox1.Text
     FMP = true;
     this.Dispose();
}
```

And You can use `Globals.UserName` anywhere in the application.If you are assigning this value to lable

```
lable1.Content=Globals.UserName;
```

Comment: Thank you. I was making a big confusion with how to use the classes. but now i'm understanding it better. Big thank you man! :D

Answer (score 1):

1) Make a public string property on the other window and on the Unload event of the Login Window, set the property's value to the textbox value.

2) Make a constructor for the other window that takes as parameter a string representing the value of the login window's textbox.

3) Make a global variable (public static string) and store the value there, on the Unload event of the Login Window.

I refered this from

[Pass textbox value from one window to another window in WPF](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ad352084-f4ae-4209-98da-bea9435825bc/pass-textbox-value-from-one-window-to-another-window-in-wpf?forum=wpf)
Also you can get idea from this Thread [Pass Values between XAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550535/xaml-and-wpf-passing-variables-to-xaml-windows)