# How to call a variable from one window to another window

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have two WPF windows: Login and Info. How can I call the variable "userName" in Login.xaml.cs to Info.xaml.cs? I want to get the input in "userName" to be displayed in a listview in Info window.

Login.xaml.cs:

```
public string userName { get; set; }

public void UNameInput_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    userName = UNameInput.Text;            
}
```

Info.xaml:

```
     <ListView x:Name="AInfoLv" FontFamily="Tahoma" FontSize="11" Background="White" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Height="264" 
                          Width="262" Foreground="Black" Margin="-4,-1,0,0">
                    <ListView.View>
                        <GridView>
                            <GridViewColumn x:Name="LabelColumn" Header="Label" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Label}"/>
                            <GridViewColumn x:Name="ValueColumn" Header="Value" Width="130" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Value}"/>
                        </GridView>
                    </ListView.View>
     </ListView>
```

Info.xaml.cs:

```
public Info()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.AInfoLv.Items.Add(new { Label = "Login" });
    this.AInfoLv.Items.Add(new { Label = " Username" });
}
```

Comment: What is the relation between Login and Info?

Comment: Hi @sac, Login is the user login window, Info is used to display user info, so actually I just want to retrieve the username enter in the Login window and display it at the listview in the Info window.

Comment: possible duplicate of [XAML and WPF - Passing Variables to XAML Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550535/xaml-and-wpf-passing-variables-to-xaml-windows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Pass via constructor.**

Change your constructor `Info()` to:

```
Info(string userName)
```

When creating info object in `Login.xaml.cs` ( here you have your `userName` input value ) pass this value to `Info` constructor, like this:

```
// userName is your input value
var oInfo = new Info(userName)
```

In Constructor of info class use passed value to show in your screen:

```
  public Info(string userName)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.AInfoLv.Items.Add(new { Label = "Login" });
        this.AInfoLv.Items.Add(new { Label = " Username" });

        // userName variable contains value of input
    }
```

**UPDATE:**

> A=Login window, B=Main window C=Info window

This is `A` class that create `B` class object:

```
class A {
   public void processB() {
      var b_obj = new b(username); // username is enter by user
   }
}
```

This is class `B` that stores `username` passed by `A` and have method to create `C` class object.

```
class B {
     private string usernameFromA;
     public B (string tmpUsername) {
        usernameFromA = tmpUsername;
     }
     public void processC() {
        var c_obj = new c(usernameFromA); 
     }
  }
```

This is class `C` that get username from `B`.

```
 class C {
       public C(string tmpUsername) {
          // Here you have your username in tmpUsername variable
       }
    }
```

Comment: Hi @Aram Kocharyan, thanks for your solution. Let say A=Login window, B=Main window C=Info window, how about if I want to pass the variable from A to C, but C has to be opened by B? I was managed to open C by A, but it is incorrect that Info window can be opened by Login window.

Answer (score 0):

```
public string userName;

public void UNameInput_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    userName = UNameInput.Text;            
}

private void LoginButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    someWindow window = new someWindow(userName);
    page.ShowDialog();
}
```

someWindow.xaml.cs :

```
public string UserName;

public someWindow(string name) //get the value from login window into someWindow using constructor
{
    InitializeComponent();
    UserName = name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You a Singleton class to store common data. 
Check the `Session` class which I have defined below.

Session.cs

```
using System;

namespace Singleton
{
    public class Session
    {
        private static object _InstanceLock = new object();

        private static Session _Instance;

        public static Session Instance
        {
            get { 
                if (_Instance == null)
                {
                    lock(_InstanceLock)
                    {
                        if (_Instance == null)
                            _Instance = new Session();
                    }
                }
                return _Instance; }
        }


        // Private constructor, so that no other class can instantiate Session class
        private Session()
        {

        }

        public String UserName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Login.xaml.cs

```
public void UNameInput_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Session.Instance.UserName = UNameInput.Text;
}
```

Info.xaml.cs

You can access the user name via `Session.Instance.UserName`

If you want to write unit tests then make your Session class implement an interface.

Answer (score 0):

If you only plan to use `userName` in one place then the easiest way to do it is to declare a `static readonly property` like below.

***Login.xaml.cs:***

```
public static string userName { get; private set; }

public void UNameInput_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    userName = UNameInput.Text;       
}
```

***Info.xaml.cs:***

```
public Info()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.AInfoLv.Items.Add(new { Label = "Login" });
    this.AInfoLv.Items.Add(new { Label = " Username" });

    // use it here
    var userName = Login.userName;
}
```